# Automatically go to next compile error in Vim

Tags: vim, compiler-errors, compilation

Using Vim, is there a way to automatically go the next line you had a compile error? Is there a way to bind that to a key? I believe this feature exists in emacs.

Let's say you compiled on the command line and now know which lines of your code have errors so you go back to editing your code using Vim. You remember the first line that had an error, so you jump to that line and fix your typo. How do you go to the next error line without exiting vim and looking at the command line again?

I understand you could use a terminal multiplexer like tmux to aid this process, but that's not really what I'm going for here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your compiler generates a file containing a list of errors (let's call it `errorfile`) you can simply do:

```
$ vim -q errorfile
```

and then use the following commands:

```
:cn[ext]        " jump to next error
:cp[revious]    " jump to previous error
:cc 12          " jump to error number 12
:copen          " open the quickfix window
```

See `:help quickfix` for the complete list of quickfix commands.

Alternatively, you can compile directly from Vim:

```
:make
```

and use the quickfix commands above.

See `:help :make` for setup/usage instructions.